# Wouldn't Eddie's actions cause a paradox?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

*The Flash* season finale just happened recently. In it, we see:

> Eddie killing himself to stop Eobard. Now, this would prevent him from being born(shown by Eobard disintegrating into nothing). Wouldn't this mean that he never existed to begin with, and thus never killed Barry's mom? Wouldn't this cause a paradox causing the timeline not to exist?

What other implications could this cause?

Comment: In fact, the whole particle accelerator should've disintegrated along with Eobard Thawne if that logic holds. But what I've learned so far in this series, logic has no place in it. I mean, time travel and keeping memories from other alternate universes? That's one huge WTF moment for me for instance. I believe there's no answer for this question, at least not yet

Comment: @yondaime008: Well, as Eobard told Cisco, it's cause he's a meta that he had those memories. Cisco is being prepped to become Vibe, I believe.

Comment: Yeah I got that much, still it is a bold and unique concept that has never been AFAIK used in time travel works, I mean what happens if someone goes more than twice back in time, what if plenty ? Could the memories overlap ? Or would they diverge? Anyway, this is not OPs question, I wonder why STAR labs existed even after Eobard never existed though.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the [Grandfather paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox). We'll have to wait for September to see how (or if) they explain this

Comment: @yondaime008: In one episode of ST:TNG Guinan "sensed" something wrong with the timeline. The one Where Tasha Yar was alive again.

Comment: On the question of the paradox, to me what happened is inconsistent within the universe of 'The Flash'. Up until the final episode time travel created some sort of alternate timeline, suggesting multiple timelines, and not a direct change in the timeline we view. For instance (SPOILER!), Eobard confesses to killing Barry's mother saying that that had not happened in his original timeline. If there is only one timeline he would have "changed" along with the change he made. He could not have any memory of the change.

Comment: @Hans that's exactly what I mean, in the first episode when the flash leapt back a day in time when Central City was threatened by the tsunami, he even saw himself running along with his past self ! That means that the time and space continum has an entire different conception in the flash with no existance of alternate timelines parrallel to each other. This is pretty risky way of looking at time travel. for instance in the room where Barry's mom was killed if this conception is used, there will be an infinite amount of flashes in the house.

Comment: One possible implication of this rather substantial paradox could be that - for no given reason - an already shut down wormhole reopens and begins to eat up the world. Maybe it is time trying to repair itself? We'll probably have to wait for Season 2 for a definitive answer... if we'll ever get one....

Comment: @BMWurm: Don't forget that ancient-looking helmet being ejected from the "wormhole". As soon as Eobard sees that he's in an awful hurry to get out of there. Also, if he was erased from history, why (1) would he be erased bit by bit starting with his left arm and why (2) does anybody still remember him? Obviously, he was physically removed from his location, but not by a time-travel paradox. Looks like some matter transfer like Star Trek's transporter.

Comment: @Hans Maybe it is similar to Marty and the polaroids, for example that of the tombstone in BttF3: it vanishes gradually too (once it's broken), yet the characters still remember that it was on that picture before. It's like Doc always said: "You're not thinking four-dimensional!"

Comment: @BMWurm: Now we're getting into woo-woo territory. :-) BttF assumes time is some sort of organic structure, capable of "healing" or "knitting" itself. But both *The Flash* and BttF are not science-fiction; they're fantasy, science-fantasy at best. There's nothing wrong with that (I like both of them) but at some point you have to stop trying to explain things in a strict scientific way.

Answer (score 1):

This is, as so many other paradoxes in pop culture, only a problem, if you look at it with a linear time in mind.
As soon as you have a linear time, stuff becomes highly complicated, specially those paradoxes appear.

Assuming you have one linear timeline, you are right. This event would prevent Eddie's successors to create the Reverse Flash in the future and therefore preventing him to kill Barry's mother. Which in return would prevent Wells from creating the Particle Accelerator, and everything else that happens after the first Episode of Season 1. So basically this would erase the entire timeline of The Flash (from his point of view). But this again would respond in the timeline to exist, since Eddie would have no reason to kill himself, giving the possibility for Eobard to exist. (Kind of a Grandfather Paradox)

But assuming you have a non-linear timeline, where you create a new timeline, each time you travel through time, this would not cause a paradox. Then, as soon as Eobard travels back in time to kill Barry's mother, he would create a new timeline. In this timeline he exists at the same time as Eddy. If Eddy then proceeds to kill himself, it would technically not stop the 'present' Eobard to exists, but the 'future' Eobard, which hasn't existed yet. This in return would imply, that Eddie's death is pointless and the Reverse Flash keeps existing.

Both versions have problems. The first, that it's a paradox, the second, that there was nothing achieved.

I would say, that's what those are the implications of that action. It is as @Hans says: It's an inconstistency with the view of time in the Arrowverse. Yondaime also pointed out, that if time is linear, at some point there would be too many versions of The Flash existant at the same moment in time.